# How do I upload photos on Super User?

Tags: support, feature-request

I figured that photos can only be posted via links. Is there any way to upload photos to a question or answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there any way to upload photos to a question or answer?

You can [upload any image(s) to Imgur](https://imgur.com/upload) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit](https://meta.superuser.com/posts/14174/edit) your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you if you don't have enough reputation yourself (10 rep points are required to inline images).

Further Reading: [Editor improvements for images and links - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/editor-improvements-for-images-and-links)